# Sum of all timediff values shows wrong value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to summarize of all timedifference values and show in format HH:mm:ss but the result is less that should be.

Here are my DDLs and my attempt so far:

```
CREATE TABLE tblproduction
    (
     OperaterID int,
     OperationID varchar(20), 
     StartDateTime datetime,
     EndDateTime datetime
    );

INSERT INTO `tblproduction` VALUES 
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-01 05:51:34', '2014-12-01 06:48:30'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-01 06:54:37', '2014-12-01 10:14:30'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-01 10:23:03', '2014-12-01 13:41:31'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-02 05:54:09', '2014-12-02 07:50:53'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-02 07:55:03', '2014-12-02 13:37:56'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-09 14:06:57', '2014-12-09 17:20:09'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-09 17:22:07', '2014-12-09 21:51:24'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-11 14:06:12', '2014-12-11 18:36:47'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-12 14:07:09', '2014-12-12 14:58:42'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-12 15:05:23', '2014-12-12 15:49:37'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-12 15:55:12', '2014-12-12 21:55:24'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-15 05:54:42', '2014-12-15 12:32:58'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-15 12:38:48', '2014-12-15 13:40:08'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-18 10:47:07', '2014-12-18 13:36:55'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-19 06:16:58', '2014-12-19 13:37:29'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-22 14:09:29', '2014-12-22 21:53:45'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-23 14:26:54', '2014-12-23 17:12:13'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-23 17:14:11', '2014-12-23 18:00:40'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-23 18:03:51', '2014-12-23 21:07:57'),
(227, 'OPEE21', '2014-12-23 21:08:56', '2014-12-23 21:46:58');

SELECT p.OperaterID
     , p.OperationID
     , p.StartDateTime
     , p.EndDateTime
     , TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIMEDIFF(p.EndDateTime, p.StartDateTime)), '%H:%i:%s') TotalTime
  FROM tblproduction p
 WHERE p.StartDateTime >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00' 
   AND p.StartDateTime <= '2014-12-31 23:59:59' 
   AND p.OperaterID = 227 
   AND p.OperationID = 'OPEE21'
 GROUP 
    BY p.OperationID;

+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| OperaterID | OperationID | StartDateTime       | EndDateTime         | TotalTime |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|        227 | OPEE21      | 2014-12-01 05:51:34 | 2014-12-01 06:48:30 | 63:48:44  |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

... and a fiddle of same
 [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/301594/1/0)

The result should be 67:52:04 but query returns 63:48:44. I don't now where I lost 4 hours.

Comment: You select `p.OperaterID` [sic], `p.OperationID`,`p.StartDateTime`, and `p.EndDateTime` but only GROUP BY `OperationID`. That's not going to work. MySQL forgives the omission. Other RDBMSs would error out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to apply SUM on TIMEDIFF result. You should first convert TIMEDIFF to seconds, than SUM it and then convert back.

```
SELECT OperaterID, OperationID, 
StartDateTime, EndDateTime,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(tblproduction.EndDateTime, tblproduction.StartDateTime)))) AS TotalTime
FROM tblproduction
WHERE StartDateTime >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00' AND StartDateTime <= '2014-12-31 23:59:59' AND OperaterID = 227 AND OperationID = 'OPEE21'
GROUP BY OperationID;
```

Comment: This solution is broadly correct, but suffers from the same problems observed above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way...

```
SELECT operaterid
     , operationid
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(EndDateTime,StartDateTime)))) total 
  FROM tblproduction 
 GROUP 
    BY operaterid
     , operationid;
```